# printing to console makes pywebview+flask exe crash

Tags: flask, pyinstaller, pywebview

Below is simple test code named `app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
import webview

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    #print('test') # <- note here
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = webview.create_window(title='app',url=app)
    webview.start()
```

Build it into exe by following command line

```bash
pyinstaller -F -w --noupx app.py
```

under dist folder there is a `app.exe`, it runs flawlessly.
But if I uncomment the print line, recomplie, it says "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".
[image]
Why?

Additional info:

1. I also tested logging, as long as there is something printed to console, it crashes.
2. If compiled without `-F` flag, exe runs with a ugly black console, printing won't make it crash.